# Cant get this code to list all the files in a directory or give me an error. it does nothing

Tags: python

Taking an online class on python. typed in from what i can tell the exact some code as the prof. but when i run it, i dont get anything back. not even a error. it just starts $ again. nothing happens at all.

```
import os

def rfile():
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:/home/zorba/Downloads/prank(2)/prank")
print(file_list)
```

it is a simple code but i cant get it to do anything. not even an error. i run it and nothing happens. im using linux so maybe im using lisdir() wrong. i dont know but i can continue with this lesson without this code working. 
the location of the file is home/zorba/Downloads/prank (2) and the file under prank (2) is called prank.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, and (assuming that this is a file, not being run in the CLI) you're never calling `rfile()`

Comment: the path is for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just define functions, you have to "call" them:

```
import os

def rfile():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:/home/zorba/Downloads/prank(2)/prank")
    print(file_list)

rfile()  # Actually call the function!!
```

Comment: ah! calling the file. Thanks You. Now it is at least giving me errors to work with! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. One thing to look into is the idea of a `main()` function, and using `if __name__ == '__main__':` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then most likely the path

```
C:/home/zorba/Downloads/prank(2)/prank
```

does not exist

Replace it with Linux path like

```
/home/someuser/somedir
```

Comment: not one path i try works. even just:    /home/username/Downloads/ or anything else. it doesn't give me an error either. it just does not do anything.

Comment: @Zorba-TheStrange As already pointed out, except for Windows path you also have a problem with the indentation, so to get your snippet to work you need to correct both issues.

Answer (score 0):

`glob` allows to use * as in Unix, so you can search, for example, for files in a directory staring with pr, like this: `pr*`.

Try this:

```
import glob

file_list= glob.glob(r'C:/home/zorba/Downloads/prank(2)/*')
```